# Nested numbered list do not break line in Jupyter Notebook Markdown

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I'm trying to create a nested numbered list within a Jupyter Notebook Markdown cell for use as a table of contents which links to titles in the document. However the items in the list which should be nested/indented just appear on the same line when the cell has been executed.

I have tried using four spaces before the numbers I want indenting (which is what I've seen people suggesting). This didn't work so I also tried 1-3 spaces and using a tab but none seem to work. Thought it may be an issue with the numbering itself and the use of fullstops (i.e. "1." and "1.1" , and not "1.1." etc), but this doesn't fix the issue either.

The indent does work if i use an asterisk in place of 1.1, 1.2 etc., but this is not the format I want.

Markdown code example:

```
1. [Intro](#intro)
    1.1 [Part A](#pA)
    1.2 [Part B](#pB)
    1.3 [Part C](#pC)
2. [Main](#main)
```

This code outputs:

```
1. Intro 1.1 Part A 1.2 Part B 1.3 Part C
2. Main
```

Desired output:

```
1. Intro 
    1.1 Part A 
    1.2 Part B 
    1.3 Part C
2. Main
```

Comment: what is the connection to python/programming? are you programmatically creating something? I am confused.

Comment: Well the rest of the Jupyter Notebook contains data analysis done in Python. Seen other q's on here asking very similar questions re this nested list issue for contents. Unfortunately none of the solutions I saw worked for me though. Take your point though, Python tag removed (it was an auto suggested tag by StackO when i was writing question).

Comment: I'm not sure [markdown (at least CommonMark)](https://commonmark.org/help/tutorial/10-nestedLists.html) allows the sub-list you're trying to achieve.  See this post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85474/how-to-write-nested-numbered-lists

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add one of the following:

- two white spaces at the end of each line, or
- a `<br>` tag at the end of each line.

for instance:

```
1. [Intro](#intro)<br>
    1.1 [Part A](#pA)<br>
    1.2 [Part B](#pB)<br>
    1.3 [Part C](#pC)<br>
2. [Main](#main)<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Results:

[image: Adding Sub-Part of Table Content]

To create a numbered list, enter 1. followed by a space, for example:

```
1. Numbered item
1. Numbered item
```

*For simplicity, you use 1. before each entry. The list will be numbered correctly when you run the cell.)*

**To create a substep, press Tab before entering the numbered item, for example:**

```
1. Numbered item
     1. Substep
```

Source (scroll down to "Numbered lists"): https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/watson-studio-local/1.2.3?topic=notebooks-markdown-jupyter-cheatsheet